# MVC Database routing erroring out in IIS 8.5

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I have an  MVC3 application that works fine on a 2008 r2 server. I have deployed it to a new 2012 r2 server. When it makes any sort of Database call it errors out. I have worked with the server team and the ports are open. We have also confirmed that we are getting data back. It seems to be some sort of MVC routing issue or something.

Really stumped on this one! Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It was an invalid column in the data base.